# my syntax read().encode("hex") is not working in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

```
def run_action(self):
     if os.path.exists(self.vars["source"][0]):
         self.ui.print_msg("Shellcode:")
         print ("\\x" + "\\x".join(re.findall("..", open(self.vars["source"][0], "rb").read().encode("hex"))))
     else:
         self.ui.print_error("%s not found" % self.vars["source"][0])
```

This is the function is not working on Python3:

```
print ("\\x" + "\\x".join(re.findall("..", open(self.vars["source"][0], "rb").read().encode("hex"))))
```

I am getting error in the above line. Can you help me write this function according to python3 syntax?

Comment: What is the expected input and actual vs. desired output?  Show the traceback of the error.

Comment: File "/root/ppk/DKMC-master/module/shellcode.py", line 21, in run_action
    print ("\\x" + "\\x".join(re.findall("..", open(self.vars["source"][0], "rb").read().encode("hex"))))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: this is the error i am getting

Comment: i am coverting  the data of a particular file in hex

Comment: can you write the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to print a byte string as hexadecimal escape codes.  Python 3 no longer supports `.encode('hex')` but there are far better ways to accomplish this in Python 2 and 3:

Python 2.7:

```
>>> data = 'data'
>>> print(''.join(['\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(b)) for b in data]))
\x64\x61\x74\x61
```

Python 3.6+:

```
>>> data = b'data'
>>> print(''.join([f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in data]))
\x64\x61\x74\x61
```

Comment: print ("\\x" + "\\x".join(re.findall("..", open(self.vars["source"][0], "rb").read().encode("hex"))))

Comment: @AbdulRafeyKhan No, Python 3 doesn't use `.encode()` on what are already byte strings. `open(...,'rb').read()` returns a byte string.

Comment: Use `data = open(self.vars["source"][0], "rb").read()` with the above.

Comment: data = open(self.vars["source"][0], "rb").read()
print(''.join([f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in data]))
\x64\x61\x74\x61